# Oracle CPQ to snowflake

Tags: oracle, etl, integration

I'm looking for some advice on how to extract data from Oracle CPQ to snowflake. I do not have any idea about how Oracle CPQ works and not sure on the data model how the system works. Is there any way we can extract Oracle CPQ transactional data into snowflake? I see rest API's can be used. But I want incremental data loads into snowflake for quotations that are created in Oracle CPQ.

Any help with suggestions or best practices to implement the incremental data pipeline from Oracle CPQ(Source) to Snowflake(Target) is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am an Oracle CPQ developer, I can assure you that there is no direct way to connect snowflake with oracle cpq or extract transactional data from CPQ.

1. You can use REST API to extract all the transactions from CPQ site as a one-time activity and transform the data into your expected structure.

Get All Transactions [GET] /rest/v15/commerceDocumentsOraclecpqoTransaction

2. Better to handle logic to push transactional data from CPQ to Snowflake

Create an action in CPQ (available in all transaction) where you can handle the API call to insert the current transaction data into snowflake database.